# Cannot instantiate the type HttpConnection

Tags: java, android, adt, httpconnection

the following is a part of my android java code,
I am getting the error "Cannot instantiate the type HttpConnection"

```
import org.apache.http.HttpConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;


public class MainActivity_test extends Activity 
{
   int resultcode,flag;    
   public static final int DIALOG_LOADING_PROGRESS = 0;
   HttpConnection con;
con = new HttpConnection();
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[HttpConnection](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpConnection.html) is an interface, and hence you cannot construct an object from it.

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.http.HttpConnection` is a interface, so you cannot create object out of it. See the [API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpConnection.html)

Comment: can i create an instance of HttpUrlConnection ??